# Format the CurTimeCtl tool in vb6

Tags: vb6

I'm using the toolbox control "CurTimeCtl" for a clock display. 
I have searched and found many ways to format labels or textboxes with the different type of displays, but I can't find one for the time ctl tool.
Is there a way to change the format to 24 hr. display?

Answer (score 0):

`TIMEMODE = true` makes the change.